# Slack Api response shows encoded characters for Japanese characters in message

Tags: character-encoding, slack-api, slack

I am using Slack API /channels.history to get messages of channel. My messages have Japanese characters. Api response is always encoded for Japanese characters as below:

Original message in Slack web interface:

```
me: テスト
```

But It returns response:

```
{...
'text': '\u30c6\u30b9\u30c8',
}
```

I don't know which encoding method is used here. Then, how can I get Japanese characters back from Api response.

Answer (score 0):

This is a unicode notation from Java. `\u` stands for unicode, probably [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). the 4 bytes in hex notation define the character.

To convert it back check for methods in your programming language to handle UTF-8 encoding.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047616/java-read-unicode-with-u) question for info on how to handle this encoding in Java.